# Adding XUL file syntax highlighting support?

Tags: major-mode, xml

I am new on Emacs and I am working on modifying firefox interface. XUL is implemented as an XML dialect.

I just need basic syntax highlighting for XUL. I found that VIM and gedit are working out of box. If I change the file extension to .xml, it works perfectly.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
(setq auto-mode-alist 
  (append '((".*\\.xul\\'" . nxml-mode))
          auto-mode-alist))
```

Comment: I suspect that should be `"#.*\\.xul\\'" and `nxml-mode`.